# Assembly- Query string

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have a query string in my environment vars that I am trying to read the parameters for. For example, I am trying to read `QUERY_STRING=m1=5&m2=60`, which is in %rdi. I have written the code, and I am trying to get to the parameters(5,60). I am not sure if what i have written is correct so far, since on the DDD it takes me so long to get to first 2 letters of QU. Can someone verify if this is correct or if there are mistakes. Keep in mind, I am only uploading the loop part of the code. Thank you very much

```
Qloop:
cmpq $'Q',(%rdi)        #the query string is in RDI, and Comparing the first character Q
je Qloop1               #if its not equal, go back to Qloop
incq %rdi               #incrementing RDI
jmp Qloop1
Qloop1:
incq %rdi
cmpb $'U',(%rdi)        #compare the next character in RDI, which is U
je findnum              
jmp Qloop               #once increments go back to Qloop1
findnum:
incq %rdi 
cmpb $'m',(%rdi)        #this is for m1
jne findnum
jmp Qloop3  
Qloop3:
incq %rdi
cmpb $'=',(%rdi)        #next letter is =
jne Qloop3
jmp Qloop4

Qloop4:
incq %rdi 
cmpb $'m',(%rdi)        #this is for m2
jne Qloop4
jmp Qloop5          #if its not equal, go back to Qloop2
Qloop5:
incq %rdi
cmpb $'=',(%rdi)        #next letter is =
jne Qloop5
```

Comment: You can use breakpoints in your debugger. Anyway, at a glance what you have written could work even if it has unnecessary things such as jumping to the next instruction.

Comment: I have used the debugger. The thing is that in the 'RDI' register, there is so much stuff that its so long to even get to the first letter. So i put a breakpoint at findnum: and at that point in the register, the address is completely different than what it was if i was to breakpoint at the starting. Is this normal?

Comment: `cmpq $'Q',(%rdi)` is a qword compare.  It will only set ZF if the 8 bytes pointed to by RDI are `0x0000000000000051` (`'Q' = 0x51`)

Answer (score 0):

**`cmpq $'Q',(%rdi)` is a qword compare**.  It will only set ZF if the 8 bytes pointed to by RDI are
`0x51 00 00 00  00 00 00 00` (x86 is little-endian, and `'Q' = 0x51`).

You could `cmpl $'QUER', (%rdi)` to check for the first 4 bytes matching.  (You can use up to a 32-bit immediate, but not a 64-bit except with `mov` to a register.)

But don't forget to check for a terminating `0` byte, or you'll eventually segfault if you don't find a match before looping into unmapped memory.

Or the other option is to require the match to start at the start of the string, so you stop looking as soon as you find a mismatch.

Your loops are also really clunky, with 2 branches instead of 1 when you're only checking for one condition.

```
Qloop:
    inc  %rdi
    cmpb $'Q', -1(%rdi)        # check the first char
    jne  Qloop                 # keep looping until we find a 'Q'
    # falls through on a match: RDI pointing at (hopefully) a 'U'
```

Or to check for a zero byte:

```
Qloop:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax      # load a byte into a register (zero-extending to fill RAX to avoid partial-register false dependencies)
    test    %eax,%eax
    jz      end_of_string
    cmp     $'Q', %al
    jne     Qloop
```

Of course this is a really inefficient way to implement strcmp.  You definitely want to be comparing multiple bytes at once, using SSE2 `pcmpeqb`.  Or if it's a memcmp and you don't have to look for zero bytes, then that's easier.  See https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S.html for an example of an optimized memcmp.  (Not many comments, and remember it has to return a -, 0, or + result instead of just equal or not-equal.)  See also https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcmp-avx2-movbe.S.html for an interesting `bswap` strategy for small inputs that avoids branches.  (It has more comments.)

glibc's strcmp is different from memcmp

Comment: Thank you! I really like your first idea 'cmpl $'QUER', (%rdi)'. I wasnt aware of that. I will def implement that and get rid of one of the loops!